# How to sum the values in a one row by grouping from multiples rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table with various teams and the Sponsor names who manages those teams.
The expenditure for each Sponsor to manage those teams are categorized by play in various columns in the same table.
Below is a sample table with Team names, Sponsor names, and expenditures...
Can someone please help me how to group on each play summing the expenditures in one row.

**Table1 sample**

```
TEAM1   TEAM2   TEAM3   Sponsor Expenses1   Expenses2
A       B       C       Play1   $1,550      $2,300
A       B       C       Play2   $1,580      $2,225
AA      BB      CC      Play1   $2,320      $2,900
AA      BB      CC      Play2   $,2464      $3,672
AAA     BBB     CCC     Play1   $3,730      $2,890
AAA     BBB     CCC     Play2   $3,852      $2,962
```

I want the output in another table as follows grouped by each play and sum the expenditures.    Please help me.

**OUTPUT**

```
TEAM1   TEAM2   TEAM3   Play1   Play2   Difference
A       B       C       $3,850   $3,805  $-45
AA      BB      CC      $5,220   $6,136  $916
AAA     BBB     CCC     $6,620   $6,814  $194
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to go dynamic, a simple conditional aggregation should do the trick

**Example**

```
Declare @Team1 varchar(50) = null
Declare @Team2 varchar(50) = null   -- Try 'BB'
Declare @Team3 varchar(50) = null

Select Team1
      ,Team2
      ,Team3
      ,Play1 = sum(case when Sponsor='Play1' then Expenses1+Expenses2 end )
      ,Play2 = sum(case when Sponsor='Play2' then Expenses1+Expenses2 end )
      ,Diff  = sum(case when Sponsor='Play2' then Expenses1+Expenses2 end )-sum(case when Sponsor='Play1' then Expenses1+Expenses2 end )
 from  @YourTable
 Where Team1 = IsNull(@Team1,Team1)
   and Team2 = IsNull(@Team2,Team2)
   and Team3 = IsNull(@Team3,Team3)
 Group By Team1,Team2,Team3
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: If they have to go dynamic, this is going to be very odd (assuming there were multiple plays) I think your assumptions are correct based of the "difference" column alond. 1 from me.

Comment: @scsimon Yes, but not impossible.  I dig the puzzles.

Comment: Thanks John Cappelletti for a quick solution.  If i have a dynamic values i which may be passing using the parameter in a stored procedure, What could be the approach please ?  But lukily there will be only two plays in my requirement.
Thanks so much once again.

Comment: @desi Just curious What type of parameter?

Comment: @desi In case of dynamic what is your difference logic?

Comment: Parameters will be on the Teams not on sponsor names.  In that case i just pull parameters names in the column values, and group names right.
Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @desi Then we just add a WHERE with your parameter ... one moment

Comment: That's it what i wanted.  Thanks so very much @John Cappelletti.

Comment: @desi See edit.  You can supply any combination of Team1,Team2,Team3.  All NULLs will give you everything

Comment: @ John Cappelletti, Thanks for simplifying the solution and every combination of parameter values in where clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pivot and difference as below:

```
Select *, [Difference] = [Play2] - [Play1] from (
    Select Team1, Team2, Team3, Sponsor, Expenses1+Expenses2 as Expenses from #Expensedata ) a
pivot(sum(Expenses) for sponsor in ([Play1],[Play2])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+------------+
| Team1 | Team2 | Team3 |  Play1  |  Play2  | Difference |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+------------+
| A     | B     | C     | 3850.00 | 3805.00 |     -45.00 |
| AA    | BB    | CC    | 5220.00 | 6136.00 |     916.00 |
| AAA   | BBB   | CCC   | 6620.00 | 6814.00 |     194.00 |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: @Kannan.  Thanks it is very short and simple to use Pivoting on data.

Answer (score 0):

You need a query that groups on Team1, Team2, Team3 and sums like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN sponsor = 'play1' THEN expenses1 + expenses2 END) as Play1
```

A similar pattern for play2, and then doing the difference should be a doddle!